# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object on NodeJs (fastify) deployment

Tags: node.js, linux, deployment, fastify

I'm trying to deploy a NodeJs project (fastify framework) on linux server. the problem is after deploying it for every request it returns 500 error with error below:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at _Reply.Reply.headers (/data/backend/node_modules/fastify/lib/reply.js:245:23)
    at Object.getAllServices (/data/backend/controller/esb.js:5762:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

I know about returning this error when pass a null argument to the functions, but there is no problem with functions and data because it works on my local server (windows) properly.
I think there is something wrong with fastify library because the error contains it files. also I see inside */data/backend/node_modules/fastify/lib/reply.js* file and there is no used Function.keys or something like that. also I update fastify library to the latest version and nothing changes.

I use try catch inside my code and before arriving to this line **res.status(200).headers().send({ "key": "value" })** everything looks okay and my functions run properly.

Comment: The expression  `reply.status(200).headers().send({ "key": "value" });` is invalid. It may not work for you regardless of platform. `Reply` does not have a `headers` method.

Comment: I try it and first add a { "Accept": "application/json" } object to it and then also remove it from expression but nothing changes.

Comment: The correct code would be `reply.status(200).header('Accept', 'application/json').send({ "key": "value" });`

Comment: Headers function does not exist in fastify reply

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was due to the response not matching the schema I had defined.

Fastify checks that the response matches the given schema when declaring the route. In my case, I had values that were `null` in output, but not marked as `nullable: true` in my schema.